# GStreamer How to get the number of current frame?

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer

I am using this code:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jderose/+junk/gst-examples/view/head:/video-player-1.0
to display a video, plus some buttons that pause and resume using code:

```
def pauseb(self):
    #code that checks if playing
    self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)

def playb(self):
    #code that checks if video is valid and is paused or stoped
    self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
```

When in pause mode I can get the time position using:

```
success, position = self.videoplayer.player.query_position(Gst.Format.TIME)
```

Converting time to frame is not always accurate.  Is there a way to find which is the number of current displayed frame (**NOT** by converting the time)?

Answer (score 2):

GStreamer pipelines aren't necessarily synchronous or linear.  They can use `queue` elements to run in multiple threads and `tee` elements to branch to multiple sinks.  Thus, the current frame could be at different values in different portions of the pipeline.

You probably have a relatively simple pipeline and would like to know the current frame relative to the final output.  In that case what I'd suggest is to add an identity element just before the sink:

`... ! identity name=frame_count ! ximagesink`

Increment the value each time the callback is invoked and then read it when needed.  My apologies for the C, but the gist of the code is:

```
GstElement* frame_count = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(your_bin), "frame_count");
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(frame_count), "handoff", 
                 G_CALLBACK(frame_count_callback), 
                 some_object_to_accumulate_the_frame_count_in);
```

Comment: 1. Adding another callback will consume time. Plus if I add a button to let user go to any point will destroy that algorithm.

Comment: If you want to factor in being able to skip, then you may need to loop through the whole file and create a timestamp->index map.  I'm not sure which--if any--video encoding formats keep absolute frame index metadata inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
success, frameNumber = self.videoplayer.player.query_position(Gst.Format.DEFAULT)
```

https://valadoc.org/gstreamer-1.0/Gst.Format.DEFAULT.html